# Modify target url in onclick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Is it possible to modify the target URL in the onclick handler? How?

I don't want to use things like `window.location = ...` because it changes the browsers' behaviour (click vs ctrl-click, opening in new tab, opening in particular window/frame etc...). **I want a clean solution - just change the url and the rest should be done itself as it would normally be.**

```
$(...).click(function () {
    if (check_some_condition) 
        // modify target url here...
        // do not want to do window.location= - this is not clean
        // as it changes the browsers' behaviour (ctrl-click, opening in particular window/frame etc.)
    return true;
});
```

Comment: ok, I meant clean instead of clear... "itself" means not using my code, "normally" means as if I not handled the click event.

Comment: the question made perfect sense to me.

Comment: Was looking at old questions, this intrigued me, why would you want to do that? Why didn't you just change the href attribute in the anchor tag?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
​$(function(){
    $("#theLink").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("href","http://tnbelt.com");
    });
});​​​​
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't help for the already running click event.

Comment: Yes, really, the solution is as simple as this! This is also what SKS converged to :-)

Comment: @TMS so, it does work for the already running click event? what does SKS stand for?

Comment: @Magne, SKS was probably one of the people posting their answers here who changed their nick (don't know now, probably Vega?)

Comment: @TMS Ah, I see. Btw, does this solution work for the already running click event?

Comment: @Magne I am not sure what you mean. Feel free to test it.

Comment: @TMS I was just referring to your first comment. If you had that confirmed/disconfirmed?

Comment: @Magne sorry I don't remember but according to the comments it seems I corrected myself. But I am not sure, you have to test it.

Comment: @Magne It appears to work, at least on Chrome. I wrote a [vanilla JS](http://jsfiddle.net/sfv2u1sx/1/) version for testing.

Comment: @teleclimber Thanks for providing the jsFiddle. I tried it in FF 48 and Edge. It works for simple clicks, but not for "open in new tab" or "save link as" scenarios which the OP wanted to be covered as well.

Comment: @Matthias in that case you could also listen to the "contextmenu" event and handle it in the exact same way as click. I tried it in Chrome and it appears to work. However there may be other ways to navigate a link that these two events don't cover though.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** Updated code because [the event handler script is executed first and then the default action takes place](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link3).

Added below version to show you that you can use `.click` as you didn't notice the quirks mode link I shared with you. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PtNfD/8/)

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#changeMe'). click (function (e) {
        var goLucky = Math.floor(Math.random()*12);
        if (goLucky % 2 == 0) {
            this.href = "http://www.google.com";
        } else {
            this.href = "http://www.hotmail.com";
        }
    });
});
```

Commented `e.preventDefault();` & `$(this).click()` as it is not required..

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PtNfD/7/)

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#changeMe').one ('click', function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        this.href = "http://www.google.com";
        //$(this).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Was typing this out in jsFiddle and then saw you had already posted. Darn!

Comment: This makes the first click do nothing (at least the user sees it like this). I don't think that such solution is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatelly I can't use `.one()` - the condition may change forth and back and forth and back... the condition must be checked every time the anchor is clicked.

Comment: @Tomas You don't need to use `.one()`. It was just an example.. You can still change the href and call as you need. Reason is : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link3

Comment: @freakish, where is your answer? I wanted to check your solution, as I cannot use `.one()`. Now I see it dissapeared!

Comment: Thank you SKS for your great help from the beginning! You finally converged to the most simple solution Gourneau originally proposed - I didn't believe it would work :-). He deserves to accept his answer, he has not received any upvotes till now.

Comment: @Tomas Sorry, my solution was wrong and other people gave correct answers so I just deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider a hidden anchor tag

```
<a id="linkId" href="myPageToGo.html" class="thickbox" title="" style="visibility:hidden;">Link</a>
```

Then you can simulate the anchor click in your code...

```
$(...).click(function () {
    if (check_some_condition) 
        $('#linkId').click();
    return true;
});
```

---

### EDIT - Alternative way

Wrap the element clicked inside a anchor tag...

```
$(...).click(function () {
    if (check_some_condition) 
        $(this).wrap('<a id="new1" />');
        $('#new1').click();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Nice trick, anyway, wouldn't then the browser condition (open in same/new tab, frame, window) be changed?

Comment: On normal links, the browser somehow decides where the new link will be open (same/new tab, frame, window). Wouldn't this solution change the behaviour?

Comment: any solution that you implement using js, would change this behaviour, unless the clicked element is an anchor.

Comment: the browser detects the options (same/new tab, frame, window) only for `<a>` tags...

Answer (score 1):

Yup.

```
$(this).attr('href', 'http://example.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers including the top comment have missed out on an important point. If a user simply right clicks the URL to perhaps open in a new tab/window, this method won't work because you're directly requesting at the location specified by the 'href' URL instead of going through the onclick event.

You could try the same at this demo fiddle mentioned on Gourneau's post.

http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PtNfD/7/

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#changeMe').one ('click', function (e) {
        this.href = "http://www.google.com";
    });
});
```